# Set alarm automomatically when schedule is saved from the DB

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have created a database for schedules, fields are (id integer primary, subject text, description text, DueDateTime DATETIME)
I was able to save the values inserted on the EditTexts and Textview to the database, but I wasn't able to create an alarm for that based on the DueDateTime value. I don't quite understand on how and when should I use the intent service, broadcastreceiver, alarm manager etc. 
My goal is to set an alarm for the schedule saved in the database when is on due  An activity will popup like this on the screen even if the app is closed or when the device is re-booted.

[image]

These are pictures. The character is a picture only and the balloon is also a picture but in there Subject name of the particular data will be written and also the these pictures are clickable, when clicked anywhere from the pictures it will be closed

Ok I found this code https://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/tag/multiple-alarms/ which could (maybe) resolve my problem but I don't understand how he use it, so I can't relate it to my app since he has a lot of things he added (some of are hard-codded) which I don't need much of them, he even added a link to download his sample.

Comment: Too broad a question

Answer (score 0):

You want to schedule an alarm manager with due date?

You can schedule in the following way.

**Code :**

```
get (Due_Date_in_milli_sec - current_date_time_in_milli_sec)
```

now schedule an alarm manager with resultant milliseconds.in case of system bootup you will need to restart alarm manager again.